# Filter SE questions by votes, views and rep

Tags: script, questions, tampermonkey

#### (Chrome only)

[image: script logo] <sup><sub>v1.2</sub></sup>    **Find good questions to answer.**

The script will *filter questions in real time*, in all Stack Exchange sites questions pages,
hiding them by score, views, user reputation and accepted answers. It only runs on pages where questions are being listed: Homepage, Unanswered and Questions.

Depending on the page and the configuration, very few questions will show up, and chances are good that they are interesting. If somebody already gave a negative vote, why look at it? If it's a new user, sorry to say, but very few *write* a good question or display research skills. Anyway, this is a tool focused on Power Answerers, who already saw too much.

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

♦ The diamond icon was on the very [stack sprite](http://cdn.sstatic.net/img/share-sprite-new.png?v=204b1e0e421b).
So took the liberty to use it and make our very own moderator menu :)

---

### Usage

Adjust the votes, views and reputation thresholds, select if questions with accepted answers should be hidden, enable the filter and save. To disable, just uncheck the *Enable filter* option and save.

<kbd>[image: ss2]</kbd>

The ranges can be modified using the button <kbd>(?)</kbd>:

<kbd>[image: ss3]</kbd>

---

### Installing

- For now, *the script is only compatible with Chrome*.
- A **browser extension for managing user scripts is required**, like [Tampermonkey](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo) or other similar extensions.
- After installing the extension, clicking the ["download / install"](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/brasofilo/FilterSO/master/FilterSO.user.js) button below should bring up a dialog asking if you want to install the script.

> #### [<kbd>Install with Tampermonkey</kbd>](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/brasofilo/FilterSO/master/FilterSO.user.js)
>
> <sub>[View source](https://github.com/brasofilo/FilterSO/blob/master/FilterSO.user.js)</sub>

---

### Code

Unfortunately, I couldn't manage to make the sliders work on Firefox. I'm by no means an expert on userscripts, all contributions and forks are welcome.

<sup>- Version 1.2 - Code revision. Better handling of the Unanswered page. New indicator counting hidden/total.</sup>
<sup>- Version 1.1 - Now, questions are hidden/shown in response to the slider  values.</sup>
<sup>- Version 1.0.1 - Bug fix, page detection must be earlier.</sup>
<sup>- Version 1.0 - Added views. UI upgrade. Custom ranges settings. Localstorage is now used instead of cookies.</sup>
<sup>- Version 0.4 - Detect if user is mod and use different icon. Expanded range of selection (votes -6/6 and rep 0/250).</sup>
<sup>- Version 0.3 - Changed script name, it's not exclusive for Stack Overflow anymore. Added /unanswered tab. More information about the filtering status on the button's tooltip.</sup>
<sup>- Version 0.2 - Support for all sites added.</sup>
<sup>- Version 0.1 - Script launch.</sup>

---

Comment: Hopefully it works! Sounds promising!!

Comment: Hey, @Unihedron, that was fast! Yep, I'll need folks to test drive it, keep me posted :)

Comment: Great idea! But that diamond menu you created might confuse mods, who already have a diamond menu (although the position is different).

Comment: @bfavaretto, is there anything on the markup that identifies a mod? Like a `<body>` class?

Comment: The `.topbar-links` div contains a `<div class="mod-only">` with mod links inside. Would that help?

Comment: @bfavaretto, can you try [this small script](http://pastebin.com/NZxFw2RP)? In theory, it will show different icons for you at SO and SOPT.

Comment: It worked, I saw a cog icon (tested at SOPT). But don't worry about us mods, we can live with having two diamond icons on the page. I should have kept my mouth shut instead of posting my previous comment.

Comment: `Invalid Script Header` on Chrome Version 37.0.2062.120 m :(

Comment: @brasofilo Never mind, I get it now. Can we have more flexible bounds?

Comment: I just installed, I don't know what can be useful yet. Maybe unlimited bounds (slider won't help). Maybe lower and upper bounds.

Comment: @bigown, I've expanded a bit the range of selection. Would be nice if the nice folks using the script opened feature requests as answers, it will be easier to discuss individually :)

Comment: @big, new version with unlimited bounds, enjoy!

Comment: Btw, why do you say it works only in Chrome :) Just tested in Safari - works wonderfully.

Answer (score 3):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

---

Support `/unanswered` tab as well.

An example: `http://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/regex`

Comment: Missed that, thx for the heads up. I added it and extended the script to all other sites. Please, reinstall as I had the update url wrong on the first version.

Answer (score 1):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)

Right now it's a global value, but I'm thinking on keeping different settings for Homepage, Questions and Unanswered pages.

Reputation is irrelevant on Homepage and Unanswered, as the user that's shown is the last editor, not the OP.

The views count changes a lot depending on the actual page. Is it worthy to have different settings for each page? Thoughts?